# How do I increase the display limit of the board (1000)

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is there a way to increase display limit? I'm using Azure Devops to track over 1000 applications that have to go through 4 tasks each. I can see them in work items but not on the board.

Comment: I suggest checking Azure DevOps documentation and possibly posting a question on one of the product-support forums. Unfortunately this is off-topic here (it's not really a programming question, but rather a tool configuration question).

Answer (score 0):

According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/object-limits?view=azure-devops#backlogs-boards-and-teams), the display limit of 1000 on the board is by design.  I am afraid that these limits cannot be changed.

You can consider adding another team and moving some work items to the other team's board.

If you need, you can try to request a feature for Azure DevOps [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion). Our engineers will prioritize suggestions with more votes. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.